# 16 bit checksum calculation

Tags: c, bitwise

I need to calculate checksum using 16-bit ones' complement addition:

```
while(byte>0)  //len = Total num of bytes
{
    Word = ((Buf[i]<<8) + Buf[i+1]) + Checksum; //get two bytes at a time and  add previous calculated checsum value

    Checksum = Word & 0x0FFFF; //Discard the carry if any

    Word = (Word>>16);     //Keep the carryout for value exceeding 16 Bit

    Checksum = Word + Checksum; //Add the carryout if any

    len -= 2; //decrease by 2 for 2 byte boundaries
    i += 2;
}

 Checksum = (unsigned int)~Checksum;
```

The above code works fine, and if I understood the concept well (to add 16 bits), add the carry if any and then take the compliment.

Are there any improvements or corrections?

Comment: What are the types of `Word`, `Checksum` and `Buf`?    It looks like `Word` must be a `uint32_t`, `Checksum` a `uint16_t` and `Buf` a `uint8_t*`, buf the information really ought to be included in the question.

Comment: You'd get better reviews if you provided at least a whole, compilable function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the packet size is less than 32k words, then you do not need to add the carry until the end:

```
while(byte>0)  //len = Total num of bytes
{
    Checksum = ((Buf[i]<<8) + Buf[i+1]) + Checksum; //get two bytes at a time and  add previous calculated checsum value

    len -= 2; //decrease by 2 for 2 byte boundaries
    i += 2;
}

 Checksum = (Checksum>>16) + Checksum; //Add the carryout

 Checksum = (unsigned int)~Checksum;
```

Comment: Ok I understand why it could be done at the end only, but I didnt understand 32k words thing.

Comment: If you have more than 32k 16-bit words, you can overflow a 32 bit integer when you add them up. With fewer than 32k words, you cannot overflow.